# struts2 Login Application using jsp with mysql database

Tags: struts2, struts-config, struts-validation

Not going on to success page. Please tell me where I'm going wrong.
1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/Login.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

2.Login.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>  
<html:form action="loginaction" method="post">
<html:textfield name="emp_id" label="Employee ID"/>
<html:password name="Pwd" label="Password"/>
<html:checkbox label="Remember" name="checkboxField1" value="aBoolean"       fieldValue="true"/>
    <html:submit value="login"></html:submit>  
    </html:form>
</body>
</html>
```

3.LoginAction:
I think the problem is here. pelase see in details and let me know

```
package controller;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts2.ServletActionContext;

public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport {
String Emp_id;
String Pwd;    

public String getEmp_id() {
    return Emp_id;
}

public void setEmp_id(String Emp_id) {
    this.Emp_id = Emp_id;
}

public String getPwd() {
    return Pwd;
}

public void setPwd(String Pwd) {
    this.Pwd = Pwd;
}

@Override
public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException{
    HttpServletRequest req = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
    setEmp_id(req.getParameter("Emp_id"));
    setPwd(req.getParameter("Pwd"));
    LoginDao ld = new LoginDao();
    if (ld.checkLogin(getEmp_id(), getPwd())) {
    return SUCCESS;
    } else
    return ERROR;
}

@Override
public void validate() {
     if("".equals(getEmp_id())){
        addFieldError("Emp_id", "ID must be filled !");
     }
        if("".equals(getPwd())) {
        addFieldError("Pwd", "Password must be filled !");
     }
     }
   }
```

4.LoginDao:

```
package controller;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginDao {   
public boolean checkLogin(String Emp_id, String Pwd) {
boolean status = false;
Connection conn = null;
try {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }   
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/timesheetdb", "root", "lion");
String query = "select Emp_id,Pwd from employee where Emp_id=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, Emp_id);
ps.setString(2, Pwd);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
if (rs.next()) {
     if (rs.getString("Emp_id").equals(Emp_id)&& (rs.getString("Pwd").equals(Pwd))) {
            status = true;
            } else {
status = false;
}
}
} catch (SQLException e) {
} finally {
if (conn != null)   
    try {
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}      
return status;
}
}
```

5.**Struts.xml:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="controller" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="loginaction" class="controller.LoginAction">
        <result name="input">/Login.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
</struts>
```

Comment: please post more details . stacktrace, expected result and what is happening currently.

Comment: thanks... on login page if we entered the id and password.. it must open success page but instead it goes to error page.... and for validations if we didnt enter the data in the user id, its not giving any validation... i dont know where i'm going wrong

Comment: please check the answer posted below

Comment: Unrelated, but using `html` as the Struts 2 tag prefix is a little misleading since lots of the tags don't actually emit any HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your variable name should match with the tags name attribute.
replace your current variable.

```
private String emp_id;
```

and generate new getters and setters for this variable.
you don't need request.getParameter() here, struts2 will do it internally.

```
    @Override
    public String execute() throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
      LoginDao ld = new LoginDao();
      if (ld.checkLogin(getEmp_id(), getPwd()))  // replace with new getters() of emp_id and Pwd
      {
          return SUCCESS;
      } 
      else
        return ERROR;
    }
```

LoginDao:
In your query you forget to pwd field compare **where pwd = ?** and you don't need equals check if result set is not empty return true. check posted code

```
String query = "select Emp_id,Pwd from employee where Emp_id=? and Pwd=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, Emp_id);
ps.setString(2, Pwd);
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

if(rs.next())
   return true;
else 
   return false;
```